# Why is this mime type deemed invalid for creating a Google Doc?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I've created a "wrapper" class for the the [python-quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/python-quickstart/blob/master/main.py) code. It works fine in my class, unless I change the mime type. In their code they created a plain text document, but I'm trying to create a Google Docs file from my code. When I try to run this code, I receive an HttpError 400 stating that my mime type is invalid. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import pprint
import httplib2
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.http
import googleapiclient.errors
import oauth2client.client


class DriveClient():
    def __init__(self):
        self.oauth2_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        self.client_secrets = 'client_secrets.json'
        self.mimetype = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
        self.flow = self.set_flow()
        self.drive_service = self.authorize_url()

    def set_flow(self):
        flow = oauth2client.client.flow_from_clientsecrets(self.client_secrets,
                                                           self.oauth2_scope)
        flow.redirect_uri = oauth2client.client.OOB_CALLBACK_URN
        return flow

    def authorize_url(self):
        authorize_url = self.flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        print('Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url)
        code = input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
        credentials = self.flow.step2_exchange(code)

        http = httplib2.Http()
        credentials.authorize(http)
        drive_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v2',
                                                        http=http)
        return drive_service

    def push_file(self, file_src, title, description=''):
        media_body = googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload(
                file_src, mimetype=self.mimetype, resumable=True)
        body = {
            'title': title,
            'description': description
        }
        try:
            new_file = self.drive_service.files().insert(body=body,
                                                     media_body=media_body
                                                     ).execute()
            pprint.pprint(new_file)
        except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as error:
            print('An error occured: %s' % error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = DriveClient()
    d.push_file('document.txt', 'mTitle', 'mDescription')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the mime type to the type of the source document, eg `application/msword`, `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` , etc. Google needs to know what the format of the incoming document is, then it will choose what kind of google doc to create.

Comment: This worked just like the mime type `text/plain` did. It created an MS Word document, but I'm specifically trying to create a Google Document.